# PrestoDB - Where are Parquet files stored?

Tags: presto

I have Presto installed along side AWS EMR.  I've created a table in Presto from a Hive table.

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table
WITH (format = 'PARQUET')
AS
SELECT * FROM <hive_table>;
```

Where are the Parquet files stored?

Or, where are any of the files stored when a `CREATE TABLE` statement is executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is stored in the Hive Warehouse, viewable on the Master node.

```
hdfs://ip-###-###-###-###.ec2.internal:8020/user/hive/warehouse/<table_name>/
```

Viewable through the following command:

```
hadoop fs -ls hdfs://ip-###-###-###-###.ec2.internal:8020/user/hive/warehouse/<table_name>/
```